# Help showing that S is a NOT closed subspace of $\ell^{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $S$ be the subspace of $\ell^{2}$ defined by 
$$S=\{\{x_{n}\}\in \ell^{2}: \text{there exists}\,N\,\text{such that}\, x_{n}=0,n\geq N\}.$$
I need to show that  $S$ is not a closed subset of $\ell^{2}$. To do that I exhibited a limit point of $S$ which is not in $S$ as follows:

Let $x=(a_{1},a_{2},...,a_{n},...)$ be point of $\ell^{2}$ that is not in $S$. Then
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }\lvert a_{k}\rvert^{2}=s<\infty \,\text{if and only if}\, \lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=n}^{\infty }\lvert a_{k}\rvert^{2}=0$$

Consider the sequence $\{x_{n}\}$ of points in $S$ given by:
$$(x_{n})_{k}=a_{k}, \text{if}\,k \leq n,\, \text{and}\, (x_{n})_{k}=0,\, \text{if} \, k>n$$

We claim that $\{x_{n}\}$ converges to $x$. To show that observe that
$$\lim_{n\to \infty } x_{n}=x \,\text{if and only if}\, \lim_{n\to \infty}\lVert x_{n}-x \rVert_{2}=0.$$

But $\lVert x_{n}-x\rVert_{2}=\left(\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\lvert a_{k}\rvert^{2}\right)^{1/2}$, then in fact we have that 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty }\lVert x_{n}-x \rVert_{2}=0.$$
This shows that $S$ doesn't contains all its limits points, and then it cannot be a closed subset of $\ell^{2}$.

What I want to know is whether my reasoning is right or not. Thanks.

Comment: This looks correct to me

Comment: $S$ is dense in $l^2$ but not equal to $l^2$ so $S\ne \bar S.$

Comment: Your reasoning is correct.

Comment: It's fine. The notation $(x_n)_k$ doesn't really mean what you mean for it to mean; $x_{n,k}$ would probably be better. (Notation for a sequence of sequences is always awkward; this is one reason to write elements of $\ell_2$ as _functions_ instead of sequences, ie $x(k)$ instead of $x_k$. Then $x_n(k)$ is clearer...)